# Getting a list of random place names and person names

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to demonstrate a product to a potential new customer.

The best source data comes from an existing customer.

I want to use the existing customer's data for the demonstration, but without compromising confidentiality in any way.

The best solution I see is to run a script that replaces all of the names, addresses and locations in the database with randomly selected names.

So, now I need to find a list of place names and person names to use as a source. Preferably this would be in a text file so it can be read easily.

This seems like a pretty common problem. Does anyone know of a site that I can download these names from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out: http://infochimps.org/, for example: http://infochimps.org/datasets/d-1990-census-name-files and http://infochimps.org/datasets/word-list-10-000-common-place-names

Comment: As they always are eventually, these links are broken

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old, but here's my 2 cents.

I wanted to also suggest that you could pull down data from public universities. For example,
http://www.wisc.edu/directories/?q=john+smith. You can find other open directories for all state schools.

All it would take is writing a script that loops through a list of names, EG http://www.behindthename.com/top/lists/us/2010/1000, and for each name searching a number of publically accessible directories and saving the first 5 results.